# Inno Setup: How to set orger wizard pages?

Tags: inno-setup

I have three wizard pages in my setup, and they have wrong order.
They open:

```
page 1.
```

[image]

```
page 2.
```

[image]

```
pagr 3.
```

[image]

I want order open: page 2 -> page 3 -> page 1.
I found article [link](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputfilepage) and it talk about function `CreateInputDirPage(const AfterID: Integer; const ACaption, ADescription, ASubCaption: String; AAppendDir: Boolean; ANewFolderName: String): TInputDirWizardPage;`. I think that `const AfterID` changes order, but i don't know how.

Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the Innosetup documentation of BackButtonClick(), NextButtonClick(), you will see these functions uses a PageID for identification of current wizard page. Some IDs are wpWelcome, wpSelectComponents,...

So if you call FirstPage := CreateInputDirPage(...) for the first page AfterID may be something like wpSelectComponents. The return value is of type TInputDirWizardPage based on TWizardPage containing an ID. Maybe this ID is the wanted ID for the next CreateInputDirPage(...) call.